# How to add a many-to-many relationship after save in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a simple ToDo app in django:
A 'box' contains multiple 'tasks', has an 'owner' (the person who created the box and has administrative privileges) and multiple 'users' (persons who can access the box and add/edit tasks).

I want to automatically add the owner to the users set. I've tried this multiple ways:
Overwriting the save():

```
class Box(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='boxes_owned', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='boxes_assigned')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        self.users.add(self.owner)
```

This does not work and neither does working with a post-save signal.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Box)
def update_box(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.users.add(instance.owner)
```

The owner won't be added to the users set.

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this?
Is this the right approach at all?

EDIT:
It seems like the owner is added correctly to users by the save function as well as by the update_box function. At least that is what the debugger tells me. However, when I try to edit the box afterwards the owner is not in the users array.
Are there any events after post_save that could mess with my relationships?

Comment: Could be that `self.owner` is null? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @brian No. self.owner is set. I don‘t get any errors. I tried debugging it, and it looked like all relationships were set correctly. However, the relationship was not updated afterwards